# Custom shape interaction in Figma

Tags: figma

When prototyping in Figma, is there any way to set up interaction exact on the shape and not the it's bounding box?

Answer (score 1):

### No

That's just not how Figma works.

You could break the shape into smaller shapes (so each part of your main shape would have a smaller bounding box) and set the same interaction for all the parts but that'd be going too far for just a prototype.